# Twig or jQuery change date d-m-Y to text date

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I have a date in twig with `{{date}}` and it display `19-09-2014`.

I want to display something like `Fri 19 September 2014`.

Is that possible with Twig ? Else with jquery ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [twig date filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) supports all the normal [PHP date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format options.

So to get what you want;

```
{{ my_date_var|date('D j F Y') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use twig `date` function to specify format:

```
{{ your_date|date('D d F Y') }}
```